Bifurcation diagram for Impedance Controllers (Stiffness Controllers) in Drake
I was wondering if the drake library already had syntactic sugar to generate bifurcation diagrams for standard controllers like the Impedance/Stiffness controllers. If not, how will one go about visualising the bifurcation diagram to visualise attractors and the gradient field on meshcat.
Thanks in advance and appreciate your instruction.

I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  A (closed-loop) dynamical system can have parameter-dependent fixed points, and therefore a meaningful bifurcation diagram. I don't associate this with Impedance/Stiffness control. Sorry if I'm missing something.
Drake would allow you to run parameter sweeps, and you can plot functions and lines, etc in Meshcat. But there is no out-of-the-box bifurcation diagram method.

This answers the question. Thank you!. What I was getting at was if I can plot out the parameter dependent Dynamic System using some ready-made function.
